# SQL break down accumulated value to single values during defined time range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as following Pic.1 and I tried to break down the cumulative revenues to a single profit for each date and each department.

However, the way I used is very stupid and cannot be applied if the date range is too large (i.e. break down the revenue from 01.01.2020 to 07.31.2020). Besides, the outcome is also not what I expected because the single profits are shown by columns, not by rows.

Is there a better way I can get expected result as below Pic 2 even the date range is very large?

My current solution:

```
declare @t1 varchar(10)
declare @t2 varchar(10)
declare @t3 varchar(10)
set @t1 = '20200701'
set @t2 = '20200702'
set @t3 = '20200703'


select M_Date, 
Department, 
[T1_revenue] as [Profit_t1], 
([T2_revenue] - [T1_revenue]) as [Profit_t2],
([T3_revenue] - [T2_revenue]) as [Profit_t3]
from(
    select M_Date, Department, Cumulated_Revenues as [T1_revenue]
    from dmf_dbo.profitTable
    WHERE M_Date = @t1
    left join (
        select M_Date, Department, Cumulated_Revenues as [T2_revenue]
        from dmf_dbo.profitTable
        WHERE M_Date = @t2
    ) AS p_t2
    on M_Date = p_t2.M_Date and  Department = p_t2.Department
    left join (
        select M_Date, Department, Cumulated_Revenues as [T3_revenue]
        from dmf_dbo.profitTable
        WHERE M_Date = @t3
    ) AS p_t3
    on p_t2.M_Date = p_t3.M_Date and  p_t2.Department = p_t3.Department
)
```

Pic 1. original data:

[image]

Pic 2. Expected result:

[image]

Comment: Be great if you could add data as formatted text instead of images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I get it.  You just want `lag()` with a default value:

```
select t.*,
       (cumulative_revenue -
        lag(cumulative_revenue, 1, 0) over (partition by department order by m_date)
       ) as profit
from t;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you so much.